# 'who' has no output

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I'm new to Arch Linux, and I just built my system up. But when I ran 'who' in urxvt, I got nothing. Anyone knows what's going on ?

BTW. I use Slim + OpenBox. And here are parts of my configure files,

rc.conf:

```
DAEMONS=(syslog-ng @network netfs dbus !bluetooth @crond @alsa @wicd @hal )
```

.xinitrc:

```
#! /bin/bash

xscreensaver &
rl=$(runlevel | grep -o [0-6])

case $rl in
    4) exec openbox-session;;
    5) exec gnome-session;;
#4) exec ck-lauch-session openbox-session;;
#5) exec ck-lauch-session gnome-session;;
esac
```

inittab:

```
id:5:initdefault:

rc::sysinit:/etc/rc.sysinit
rs:S1:wait:/etc/rc.single
rm:2345:wait:/etc/rc.multi
rh:06:wait:/etc/rc.shutdown
su:S:wait:/sbin/sulogin -p

# -8 options fixes umlauts problem on login
#c1:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 tty1 linux
c2:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 tty2 linux
c3:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 tty3 linux
c4:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 tty4 linux
c5:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 tty5 linux
c6:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 tty6 linux

# Serial Virtual Console for KVM and others VMs
#s0:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 9600 ttyS0 linux

# Hypervisor Virtual Console for Xen and KVM
#h0:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -8 38400 hvc0 linux

ca::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -t3 -r now

# Example lines for starting a login manager
#x:5:respawn:/usr/bin/xdm -nodaemon
#x:5:respawn:/usr/sbin/gdm -nodaemon
#x:5:respawn:/usr/bin/kdm -nodaemon
x:45:respawn:/usr/bin/slim >/dev/null 2>&1

# End of file
```

Comment: @Dutor: off topic. This will probably be migrated.

Answer (score 2):

The `utmp` and `wtmp` databases are updated by programs themselves, meaning they must have sufficient privileges. The `/var/run/utmp` file is normally set to `0664` and owned by `root:utmp`, therefore `/usr/bin/urxvt` must have at least *setgid* to `utmp` group – which it isn't, so you have to `chown :utmp` and `chmod g+s` it manually.

The same applies to `slim`, but you can instead edit your X session script to run `sessreg -a -l $DISPLAY $USER`.

Answer (score 0):

Your system cannot find /var/run/utmp or /var/log/wtmp for some reason. It might be that you haven't `touch`ed them, or maybe your programs aren't configured to use it.

Try `touch`ing it, and see if that helps.